# Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) package that allows specifying asymmetric prior?

Tags: software, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

Are there any packages there any LDA packages out there that allow you to specify the full asymmetric prior? I know Mallet uses asymmetric priors, but I don't believe it allows you to specify them.

Answer (score 1):

The [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html) topic modelling toolbox in python seems to support asymmetric priors. [This](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) documentation says:

> alpha can be set to an explicit array = prior of your choice. It also support special values of ‘asymmetric’ and ‘auto’: the former uses a fixed normalized asymmetric 1.0/topicno prior, the latter learns an asymmetric prior directly from your data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Definitely helpful! I'd prefer a package that uses Gibbs sampling, but this might be my best bet.

Comment: I know that the [Matlab topic modelling toolbox](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/programs_data/toolbox.htm) uses Gibbs sampling, but does not support asymmetric priors readily. It should not be too difficult to modify their original code to use asymmetric priors.